# Декомпиляция .арк

Tags: android, java

Не могу декомпилировать :

```
D:\Decompile\dex2jar-0.0.9.15>dex2jar.bat D:Decompile\Darkminstrel-birthday_full
_3_12.apk
this cmd is deprecated, use the d2j-dex2jar if possible
dex2jar version: translator-0.0.9.15
dex2jar D:Decompile\Darkminstrel-birthday_full_3_12.apk -> D:Decompile\Darkminst
rel-birthday_full_3_12_dex2jar.jar
. while process file: [D:Decompile\Darkminstrel-birthday_full_3_12.apk]
.. ROOT cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'D:Decompile\Darkminstrel-birthday_full_3_12
.apk' does not exist
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:56)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:40
)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.readDex(DexFileReader.jav
a:143)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main.doFile(Main.java:63)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Done.
```

Comment: Отблагодарить сообщество можно в комментах к вашим вопросам, проставленнием "плюсиков" в карму etc. Но точно не публикацией повторяющихся "вопросов" не относящихся к теме форума. Подобное поведение в сообществе не принято, засим и столько минусов вам поставили. 

А лучшим способом отблагодарить сообщество будет составление подробного вопроса, описывающего вашу проблему и описание её решения, также максимально развёрнуто. 

Привет с метео-станции из-за полярного круга. =)

Comment: @niknva, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: На правах автора приложения, которое пытался декомпилировать @niknva, я просто хотел узнать, как успехи?

Comment: @D.M., пакет "com.darkminstrel.birthday_full" - ваш?
Вот это встреча =)

Answer (score 2):

Просто подучите английский язык. Гарантирую, что 80% всех ваших проблем вы сможете решить самостоятельно.

В приведенном выше выводе из консоли ясно сказано: **используйте "d2j-dex2jar", если это возможно. т.к "dex2jar" устарел.**

---

Примечание: используется точно таким же образом, как и устаревшая версия.